# JQuery - Checkbox not checking (visually)

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to dynamically change the `checked` value. But visually checkbox constantly unchecked.
Although the `checked="checked"` is present.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" /><br>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  var chk = $("#chk").attr("checked");
  $("#chk").attr("checked", !chk);
});
```

Link on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/USHRw/4/ - try click on the button several times.

How to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.prop()` not `.attr()`.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var chk = $("#chk").prop("checked");
    $("#chk").prop("checked", !chk);
    if (!chk === true) {
        $("#lbl").text("Checked");
    } else {
        $("#lbl").text("Unchecked");
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/USHRw/5/)**

As the docs for [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) say:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` for jQuery 1.9 and above, your code is working for jQuery 1.8
.3 check it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/USHRw/7/)

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/USHRw/8/)** using `prop()` for jQuery 1.9.1

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var chk = $("#chk").attr("checked");
    $("#chk").prop("checked", !chk);
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that his code will work again in newer versions of JQuery (v3.3.1 and above in JsFiddle)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  var checked = $("#chk").prop("checked");
  $("#chk").prop("checked", !checked);
    if (!checked === true) {
        //Checked Event Code
    } else {
        //Unchecked Event Code
    }
});
```